# Mocha before doesn't let me go next

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, chai

I have a problem with mocha tests, i'am trying to make  initial setup to make some tests. Unfortunately i have no idea why mocha doesn't show me any errors. Promise.all is working correctly and shows me results but it doesn't let me go to the next step -> tests.

It is working if only i remove second promise (createCourseAndReview) and all tests pass (i mean it's executing tests).

```
before(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const createUser = User.remove({}, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return Promise.reject();
      }
      User.create({
        googleId: "googleId",
        name: "name",
        email: "email@email.com",
        phone: "000000000"
      })
        .then(res => {
          token = createToken({ googleId: res.googleId });
          return Promise.resolve();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return Promise.reject();
        });
    });
    const createCourseAndReview = Course.remove({}, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return Promise.reject();
      }
      Course.create({
        title: "Tytuł",
        shortTitle: "Krótki tytuł",
        video: {
          link: "http://",
          title: "Tytuł",
          shortDescription: "video desc"
        },
        content: "zawartość",
        image: "gosc.jpg",
        duration: "2 tygonie",
        price: "120zł/h",
        shortDescription: "Krótki opis",
        technologies: ["Java", "Javascript"],
        maxMembers: "12/12",
        reviews: [],
        comments: []
      })
        .then(doc => {
          Course.update(
            { _id: doc._id },
            {
              $push: {
                reviews: {
                  content: "Zawartość",
                  grade: 5,
                  user: {
                    googleId: "googleId",
                    name: "name",
                    email: "email@email.com",
                    phone: "000000000"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ).then(() => {
            return Promise.resolve();
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return Promise.reject();
        });
    });

    Promise.all([createUser, createCourseAndReview])
      .then(results => {
        console.log(results);
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        reject();
      });
  });
});
```

I don't get any errors and i don't know how to resolve this kind of issue.

Comment: Your source is a bit of a mess. You're not converting your callback-style methods correctly to promises, and you _really_ should try to avoid the `new Promise` pattern. You also don't need to have a catch statement for every promise chain, just the last one.

Comment: I'm going to spend a couple of minutes doing a rewrite of your source, avoiding async/await but removing some of the bad design patterns.

Comment: In hindsight I'm not sure if the API's you're calling are correct. It seems that `Users.remove()` is callback-style but `User.create()` is promise style. If you didn't write `User`, I assume that this is also incorrect as these paradigms are usually not mixed. If you did write it, I would really suggest you go back to those functions first and make everything promise-style.

Comment: But in promise.all i can show correct result.

Comment: 75% of your source code desperately needs a rewrite. Try to avoid the mindset of 'hacking until it works'.

Comment: OK. But how can i rewrite it ?

Comment: Step one for me would be to go to your User object and make sure every function uses promises and none use callbacks. Right now it looks like the class does both at the same time.